# I am gettting an error when using pandas parse_date

Tags: python, pandas

I am running the following python code block using pandas parse_date but get a syntax error, since I am still struggling with finding the proper package for my atom editor to help me with syntax error detection I would appreciate any help I can get on this.

```
marketing = pd.read_csv.('/Users/name/Folder/marketing.csv', parse_dates=['date_served', 'date_subscribed', 'date_caneled'])
```

Comment: Please show your date format in csv file. And please remove dot after read_csv

Comment: @TinyCookie You can try `kite` for atom, it will do line-completion and also show you in-line syntax documentation.

Comment: @liming sorry I don't understand what you mean by show my date format? Where?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the dot before the first paren.

```
marketing = pd.read_csv.('/Users/name/Folder/marketing.csv', parse_dates=['date_served', 'date_subscribed', 'date_caneled'])
```

Comment: That was definitely it. Thank you!